# Does jQuery "short circuit" calls on empty collections?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the following jQuery:

```
$container = $('#container');

$container.find('.foo').hide(500).remove();
```

There's no point in calling anything past `$container` if there is no `#container` element on the page, so I **could** do this:

```
if ($container.length > 0) { // Is there such an element?
  $container.find('.foo').hide(500).remove();
}
```

But is there any point to checking? **If `$container` is an empty collection, will jQuery automatically ignore the rest of the calls?**

I've verified that the code in an `each` callback is never called on empty collections, but I'm not sure how to test this for other chained methods; I don't know whether `hide()` is being called or not, for instance.

Comment: if ($container.length) {} will suffice.

Comment: @ScottE - you're right, that would work fine. The only reason I didn't do that is an aversion to implicit type conversion in Javascript because it's often screwy, but non-zero numbers being trueish is a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of $().find()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L19) it loops through this.length:

```
for ( i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
length = ret.length;
// ...
```

So I would say, you don't need it, the loop never gets executed anyway.
Usually jQuery just does nothing if your selector returns an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes.

When `#foo` does not exist and I call:

```
$('#foo').html('bar');
```

I usually get an `undefined` error. The selector won't throw the error, but the following functions probably will.

Answer (score 0):

The if is a good option to prevent the system runs the .find .hide e .remove functions, wasting memory/time.